# What is the event dispatching when abandoned cart save it's data?

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, event-observer, quote

I need to save some additional data in `sales_flat_quote` table. So what is the event which dispatching when the abandoned cart data saves in this table?

EDIT: I need to save item names comma separately in the sales_flat_quote table by adding a new column. Hope a data script can be used to fill the column. But How can I do this  without an event observer?

Please be kind enough to provide suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we use `checkout_cart_save_before` event for this? Please any suggestion on this would be really helpful.

Comment: Please more suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following events was fulfilled the requirement.

```
sales_quote_collect_totals_after

onepage_checkout_index_middle
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no specific event triggered for abandoned cart (as far as I
   know).
2. You can check it manually using a cron job.
3. You can use `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_logout` event to check the `sales_flat_quote` table which aren't present in `sales_flat_order` table. This will give you the abandoned quotes (in other words abandoned carts).

> **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148275/when-does-magento-consider-a-cart-to-be-abandoned-wheres-that-time-limit-set) will give you the exact answer for your question**.

note:

> You cannot rely on `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_logout` event completely as there are many untraceable instances, which will result in abandoned carts viz.
>
> - User closing browser window
> - Sudden power off etc.

**Therefore cron would be the better Idea!**

**or**

There are some paid extensions to do this job for you.

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Adjustware/extension/1290/abandoned-carts-alerts-pro
- http://www.extendware.com/abandoned-cart-reminder-magento-extension.html

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: have you gone through this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148275/when-does-magento-consider-a-cart-to-be-abandoned-wheres-that-time-limit-set` that'll tell you after what event abandoned cart is saved